# O que é um Cluster Distribuído?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, nosql

Estou estudando sobre banco de dados, especificamente o mongoDB. Então, diante de minha ignorância, gostaria de saber o que essa expressão, `cluster distribuído` ou `consulta em cluster distribuído`, significa.

Answer (score 0):

> Um sistema de processamento distribuído ou paralelo é um sistema que interliga vários nós de processamento (computadores individuais, não necessariamente homogéneos) de maneira que um processo de grande consumo seja executado no nó "mais disponível", ou mesmo subdividido por vários nós. Conseguindo-se, portanto, ganhos óbvios nestas soluções: uma tarefa qualquer, se divisível em várias subtarefas pode ser realizada em paralelo.
>   (Wikipedia)

Recomendo a leitura desse [artigo](https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/o-que-e-banco-de-dados-distribuido/?trace=1519021197&source=single) sobre Banco de Dados Distribuído para entender como esse conceito se aplica ao seu banco de dados MongoDB.